# How do you get the types of non-common properties in a union type?

Tags: typescript

Say that I'm working with actions with a common property of "type":

```js
type Action =
  | {
      type: 'OPEN';
      url: string;
      incognito: boolean;
    }
  | {
      type: 'CLICK';
      count: number;
    }
  | {
      type: 'SAVE';
      link: string;
    };
```

I want to write a function that will process the non-common properties. For the sake of this example, let's say that I want to replace "http" with "https" in the properties `url` and `link`.

#### Attempt #1

```js
function run(action: Action) {
  Object.keys(action).forEach(field => {
    if (field === 'type' || typeof action[field] !== 'string') {
      return;
    }
    const value = action[field]; // <-- ERROR
    action[field] = value.replace('http://', 'https://'); // <-- ERROR
  });
}
```

Error: `field` is inferred to have a type of `string`, which cannot be used to index type `Action`.

#### Attempt #2

I tried to cast the result of `Object.keys` to the keys of type `Action` to avoid getting `string`.

```js
function run2(action: Action) {
  (Object.keys(action) as Array<keyof Action>).forEach(field => {
    if (field === 'type' || typeof action[field] !== 'string') {
      return;
    }
    const value = action[field];
    action[field] = value.replace('http://', 'https://'); // <-- ERROR
  });
}
```

Error: `keyof Action` only gets the common property (`type`), which means that `field` has type `never` after the conditional.

#### Attempt #3

In order to try to get the other properties of `action` based on its `type` property, I tried to make the function generic:

```js
type ActionType = Action['type'];
type ActionWithType<T> = Extract<Action, { type: T }>;

function run3<T extends ActionType>(action: ActionWithType<T>) {
  (Object.keys(action) as Array<keyof ActionWithType<T>>).forEach(field => {
    if (field === 'type' || typeof action[field] !== 'string') {
      return;
    }
    action[field] = action[field].replace('http://', 'https://'); // <-- ERROR
  });
}
```

Error: TypeScript doesn't know that `action.field` is of type `string`.

Why not? What is incorrect with the code in attempt #3?

**Question: How do I properly get the types of non-common properties of a tagged union type?**

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=44&ssc=36&pln=44&pc=41#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-KlwtFEoFQtlouVPCVKtwasq1Vq9QaAGZcDZ-YCACqp+sjKmJ1N0Fvr3f7tAAdTUBx3kC9W5u7xYAA8JACvefUBLiCmaFAt1AJhXCUODtKgGxGqgK73lAECvhAqDnK6n63hAVyOkMm5dFewA3qm96BkW1qzPMwBLCsawZs6yHup6PorH6n44Xhd4PoG2y7PscBHFmEYouQ0ZhnGuZJgQPypum7ZZpCMIJvmiKWhk+AlliraVuQjbSfWmk0uCvb9nAfJjtKcripK46mVO8gzrgURAA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make guarantees about the types of other properties unless your types are constrained to only allow properties of a certain type:

```
interface MyAction {
  type: string;
  [v: string]: string;
}

interface OpenAction extends MyAction {
  type: "OPEN";
  url: string;
}

interface ClickAction extends MyAction {
  type: "CLICK";
  href: string;
}

interface SaveAction extends MyAction {
  type: "SAVE";
  link: string;
}

type Action = OpenAction | ClickAction | SaveAction;
```

Now `value` is inferred to be of type `string` and all is good:

```
function run(action: Action) {
  Object.keys(action).forEach(field => {
    if (field === 'type') {
      return;
    }
    const value = action[field]; // <-- NO ERROR
    action[field] = value.replace('http://', 'https://'); // <-- NO ERROR
  });
}
```

However, seeing as this is already fairly "duck-typy" code, why not just:

```
function run(action: Action) {
  Object.keys(action).forEach(field => {
    if (field === "type") {
      return;
    }
    const unsafeAction = action as any;
    const value = unsafeAction[field];
    if (typeof value === "string") {
      unsafeAction[field] = value.replace("http://", "https://");
    }
  });
}
```

...or, seeing as how the above mutates its parameters (avoid side-effects at all cost!), here's a concise, pure version of the same that returns a new `Action`.

```
const run = (action: Action):Action =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(action).map(([k, v]) => [
      k,
      k === "type" || typeof v !== "string"
        ? v
        : v.replace("http://", "https://")
    ])
  ) as Action;
```

Comment: Hey spender, thanks for the quick response! Your response solved the problem for the example I gave in the question, but I couldn't get it to work for my actual case. I updated the question to reflect the diversity of the properties in Action.

Extending your suggestion a bit, I'm left with `action[field]` just being `any` which is undesirable since I'd like to keep type-safety if possible: [Playground](shorturl.at/cGK38)

Comment: @dkthehuman With different prop-types, I think you're out of luck trying to enforce this at compile-time. If it were me, I'd go with the last code example I provided.